# How do I mark equipment as "in use" during maintenance?

Tags: scheduling

I want to mark a piece of equipment (resource) as unavailable from the start of one activity till the end of a different, and unlinked activity. For example, I clean a piece of equipment on Monday from 8 AM - 10 AM, and I use it on Tuesday from 3 PM - 11 PM. I want the resource to show as "in us"e from the start of the cleaning through the end of the use (including the time from Monday at 10 AM through Tuesday at 3PM), not just during the two activities (cleaning and use).

Answer (score 1):

Schedule the resource between 10 am through 3 pm and link them in between the cleaning and its use with FS dependencies.  Title it "Equipment Staging" or something like that.  Make this task fixed duration and load the number of days (hours in your example's case) with zero hours of work.  This will disable costs being accrued during that time but will create a lapse in time.